# Showing $SO(1, 2)$ is a smooth manifold using multivariable calculus methods

Tags: multivariable-calculus, smooth-manifolds

I'm looking for an analytic method of showing that SO(1, 2) is a smooth manifold.
I know it goes like defining
$$ F: M_{3x3} \rightarrow S_3$$
$$ F(A) = A^T\begin{bmatrix}
    -1       & 0 & 0\\
0       & 1 & 0\\    
0       & 0 & 1\\\end{bmatrix} A-\begin{bmatrix}
    -1       & 0 & 0\\
0       & 1 & 0\\    
0       & 0 & 1\\\end{bmatrix}$$
and
$$ SO(1, 2) = \{A \in M_{3x3}\  | \ F(A)=\textbf{0}, \det A=1 \} $$

Then being a manifolds should follow from showing that F is surjective, but I don't really get why it works.

Comment: You need to show that $dF$ is surjective, not $F$.

Comment: and then it follows from rank theorem?

Comment: It follows from regular level set theorem (which is a consequence of the rank theorem)

Comment: Now it makes more sense, thanks